# Load the page inside of IFRAME using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, iframe

how about loading your page using IFRAME ? I was thinking if this is possible ..

Example, i have this iframe below.

```
<iframe id="iframe" width="1024" height="600" src="http://www.sample.com"></iframe>
```

I want the **www.sample.com** page to load inside this iframe by not simply add the URL into **src** attribute, instead I'll get the current page data using ajax and to load using IFRAME tag. I'm thinking about this because I have a big problem on IFRAME cache most of the time.

I also try this thing but, it does not work perfectly on my end.

```
<iframe id="iframe" width="1024" height="600" src="http://www.sample.com?random=1422841682605""></iframe>
```

**random** is change everytime i load this iframe.

I want to apply it on my responsive tool like on the image below. If you need an actual view ***[click here](http://responsivetool.4nton.com/)***.

[image]

Thanks guys if have some idea out there .

Comment: If www.sample.com is not the same domain as your page with the iframe, you can't just use AJAX.

Comment: Thanks sideroxylon..but is there a way to prevent iframe cahce? do you have any idea?

Answer (score 6):

You can still use src but supply data URL like this:

```
src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + 
    encodeURIComponent( // Escape for URL formatting
        '<!DOCTYPE html>'+
        '<html lang="en">'+
        '<body><h1>Another document!</h1></body>'+
        '</html>'
    );
```

Comment: Thanks sir..but I'm confuse of this code. can you give me more hint so I can apply this on my code?

Comment: By using ajax you can request html of the page you need to show.
When you get html of that page received simply do: 
`src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent( thatHtml );`

Comment: sir, please look at my updated question above, for more example. Any help from you would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the location of an iframe with Javascript with a few different methods.

```
var frame = document.getElementById("iframe");
frame.src = "http://www.sample.com";
frame.contentWindow.location = "http://www.sample.com";
frame.contentWindow.open("http://www.sample.com");
```

Of course, you must be very careful with iframes.  If the iframe points to a foreign domain (ie: "Cross-Origin", ie: NOT the same domain on which the main web page is hosted) you will breach browser security policies and will throw errors if you try to manipulate / read many properties.

Also note that by changing an iframe element's `src` attribute, the iframe will automatically travel to the new location.  However, if you use one of the other two methods I suggested, the `src` attribute of the iframe element will not change (even though the iframe's content points to a new location).

If you need to get the location of an iframe, you can try:

```
iframe.contentWindow.location.href;
```

Again, however, if the iframe is pointing to a site that is not hosted on the same domain, this will cause an error.  To be safe, use `try {} catch (e) {}` blocks.

Comment: I tried to use your codes but I can't find it working on my end. I updated my question above, hope this will help you and for me also.

Comment: doesn't use AJAX

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use "http://" before the link, example:

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add **http://** on my code but i have already on my iframe src.

Answer (score 1):

If `www.sample.com` is on the same domain, you can just do this:

```
<div id = "targetDiv"></div>
<script>
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#targetDiv').load('www.sample.com');
});
</script>
```

Though, if it is the same domain, you'd probably use `.load('/');`

Comment: No sir .. both not the same domain name .

Comment: Then AJAX alone is not your friend.

Comment: doesn't use an iframe